# SIMBL "[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to isntance"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, simbl

I am currently tinkering with SIMBL, attempting to make my own plugin. I am currently following the tutorial provided at http://www.culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering and am entirely sure that I have followed it exactly. However, when I compile and place my bundle in my SIMBL directory, I get the following error message in my logs:

```
3/26/12 1:52:33 PM  1:52:33 PM  SIMBL Agent[37793]  37793   -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20029e600
3/26/12 1:52:33 PM  1:52:33 PM  SIMBL Agent[37793]  37793   -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20029e600
```

There is currently no code in the bundle, so I am certain that this isn't a code problem. Below is the plist for my bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034Identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFPlugInDynamicRegisterFunction</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFPlugInDynamicRegistration</key>
    <string>NO</string>
    <key>CFPlugInFactories</key>
    <dict>
        <key>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</key>
        <string>MyFactoryFunction</string>
    </dict>
    <key>CFPlugInTypes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</key>
        <array>
            <string>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>CFPlugInUnloadFunction</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>MySamplePlugin</string>
    <key>SIMBLTargetApplications</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>BundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.Finder</string>
            <key>MaxBundleVersion</key>
            <string>412</string>
            <key>MinBundleVersion</key>
            <string>412</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Most everything was generated by XCode 3, so I am unsure what the problem could be. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** I found this issue to be arising from another plugin, unrelated to the one I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have a string somewhere where there should be a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I found the issue was another plugin. When I disabled it, the error went away.